# Heroku toolbelt installation not working

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I have Heroku installed in my machine and I can check the version just for verification as you can see in the picture.

[image]

So now, I want to install heroku toolbelt but I am having problems to do so.
Everytime I go to the link: https://toolbelt.heroku.com/windows. I get redirected to this link:https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli which is just to install heroku.(which I already have installed).

Is there another way around I can use to intall toolbelt?

Comment: `Heroku` **IS** `Heroku Toolbelt` :) You already have it installed as you nicely shared the command prompt screenshot :)

Comment: Weird. Because I was follwoing a tutorial in which the instructor first installed Heroku from heroku.com, installed toolbelt from toolbelt,heroku.com and then using the command: heroku --version he showed both heroku version and toolbelt.
Or is this now a sort of update that went on Heroku which everything is in one now?

Comment: I don't know what tutorial you were following, but Heroku = Heroku Toolbelt = Heroku CLI means the same thing in your local computer and always has been :)

Comment: but right now I tried to create a new app using the command: heroku create and it is failing to do so.

Comment: What's the error/failure message? :)

Comment: I went to git bash and typed heroku create and it gave me a link. But when I types the command: heroku open it says: No app specified

Comment: You also got app name and this error message means you need to add into your command line `-a [generated_or_created app name]`. See more from documentation: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-the-cli

Comment: Actually it's all fine now. Think the problem is because first of all I was trying to use the heroku commands on the normal prompt and not on git bash. And on git bash was not in the project directory.
Appreciate the support